# VBA Excel - Find/Replace text in .svg file not working

Tags: excel, vba, svg

I modified a VBA macro i found at https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/multiple-find-and-replace-text-string-files-in-folder.30905/ so that I can change RGB values in svg files, without any issues, (it recognizes the pattern in column D and changes with what I wrote in column F). Now, I would like to use the same macro to add text to various shapes but i get back exactly the same file. The pattern to be changed would be `id="Item1" style="fill: rgb(24, 161, 205); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity:0.9; stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap;butt; stroke: rgb(0, 144, 188); />` and it should be replaced with `id="Item1" style="fill: rgb(24, 161, 205); stroke-width: 1; fill-opacity:0.9; stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap;butt; stroke: rgb(0, 144, 188); /><text xml:space="preserve" style="" x="" y="" id="Item1-Text"><tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="Item1-text" x="" y="">Item1</text>`. If I replace `id="Item1"` with the rest I do get some replacement, but there is a block left. Why is acting like this?
Could someone please advise?

````
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840574/find-and-replace-string-in-all-excel-files-in-folder
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFil As Object
Dim objFil2 As Object
Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim StrFileName As String
Dim StrFolder As String
Dim strAll As String
Dim FindStr As String, ReplaceStr As String

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 'enable microsoft scripting runtime
StrFolder = "C:\TEMP\abc\" 'choose folder to go through
StrFileName = Dir(StrFolder & "*.svg") 'choose extension to find and replace

Do While StrFileName <> vbNullString
    Set objFil = objFSO.opentextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
    strAll = objFil.readall
    objFil.Close
    Set objFil2 = objFSO.createtextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
    For i = 2 To Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With regex
            .MultiLine = True
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = False '\\ Change to true if you don't want case sensitivity
            .Pattern = Range("D" & i).Value
            strAll = .Replace(strAll, Range("F" & i).Value)
        End With
    Next i
    objFil2.Write strAll 'choose what to find and replace *case sensitive
    objFil2.Close
    StrFileName = Dir
Loop
Set regex = Nothing
End Sub```
````

Comment: Your replace element ends before the text you insert. You should use an xml aware way of doing things and replace simple search/replace with XSLT which you can call from VBA

Comment: @KevinBrown Thank you, do you mean `strAll = .Replace(strAll, Range("F" & i).Value)`?  I had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340508/vba-find-and-replace-a-xml-node but honestly I could not grasp much.